# How to move a form field inside a container

Tags: 7, forms

I have a "Birthday" field and the "date" module automatically adds the countainer around it.

Now I'm adding another field "Show Birthday". How can I display that field within the container?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fieldset is added by the [`theme_date_combo()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date.theme/function/theme_date_combo/7) function, which is on the element itself, not the wrapper (i.e. `$form['field_birthday']`).

To get this to work you'll need to temporarily move the Show Birthday field into the `date_combo` field, like so:

```
function MYMODULE_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_birthday'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_show_birthday'] = $form['field_show_birthday'];
  unset($form['field_show_birthday']);

  $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_article_node_form_validate';
}
```

Importantly, you'll also need to move that field back to where it originally was when the node form is validated. You won't get any errors if you don't, but the `field_birthday` value simply won't be saved.

```
function MYMODULE_article_node_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['values']['field_show_birthday'] = $form_state['values']['field_birthday'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_show_birthday'];
  unset($form_state['values']['field_birthday'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_show_birthday']);
}
```

The above assumes you're making changes to the Article node form, just replace `article` with the name of your content type in the code. If your fields are inside another fieldset you might need to dig a bit further into the form array to find out how to access the precise field, but the logic will remain the same.

This is the result I get with that code (using admin theme):

[image: screenshot]

I've tested both add and edit node forms and they seem to work perfectly using this method.

Comment: you are a genius! Your solution worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: @MotoTribe No worries, glad it helped :)

Comment: Any idea at all how do you do this for a file? The upload / remove is broken before it seems to hit form validate... Seems to be a nightmare

Comment: @WestieUK I'm struggling to picture what you're trying to do...would you be able to post a new question with a screenshot of what-you-want-get-where (the same as Mototribe has done would be v helpful). I'll be glad to run a couple of tests if you do. I suspect it's to do with the order validation functions are run in

Comment: I would add to this answer in validation function:  `$form['field_show_birthday'] = $form['field_birthday']['und'][0]['field_show_birthday'];
  unset($form['field_birthday']['und'][0]['field_show_birthday']);` just to end clean. Otherwise locale module is giving a notice.

Answer (score 0):

Some vague memory tells me that Date module does something weird with fieldsets, but this would work in most circumstances.

Implement hook_form_alter in your module, then move your field into the birthday container, something like this:

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id = 'yourform') {
    $field_to_move = 'fieldname';
    $form['birthday'][$fieldname] = $form[$fieldname];
    unset($form[$fieldname]);
  }
}
```

You'll need to use the correct field names of course - an easy way to figure them out is to use `dpm($form)` inside your 'if' to see the array keys and values in the form array.

Comment: The problem is that `$form['birthday']` and `$form[$fieldname]` will both have `'#tree' => TRUE` as a property, so you'd have to manipulate the `$form_state` during validation and move the field back to the root, so the submit handler will still work properly

Comment: Ugh, what a pain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#field-whatevet').appendTo('fieldset#whatever');
```

eh eh

I hope this helps you.

Comment: What? Don't you like jQuery?

Comment: I think this is a slick shortcut, especially given how complex the "Drupal way" is ;-)

Comment: Of course it is a shortcut. It is usefull for the meantime you find the php solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [drupal form api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

As far as I know, those kind *customization* fit into the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) in a custom module (you have to create it, but a base module is really easy to do).

Then, as cam8001 suggested, you have to choose how to move the *show birthday* field where you want - I can suggest you to do a `var_dump($form);` to see the form array structure.

Simple example (replace [yourmodulename] and [FORM_ID]!):

```
function [yourmodulename]_form_[FORM_ID]_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form['#after_build'][] = '_choose_a_custom_function_name';
}

function _choose_a_custom_function_name($form, $form_state)
{
    // var_dump($form); // need to see the form structure?
    // lets move the title and body fields in a group
    $form['group_whatever']['title'] = $form['title'];
    $form['group_whatever']['body_field'] = $form['body_field'];
    // delete the original
    unset($form['title']);
    unset($form['body_field']);
    // remember to return the form!
    return $form;
}
```

I can't give you more specific help because I don't know exactly the field structure used by the date module, so give out a dump and see.

Also, moving a key usually means to duplicate it - remember to unset the original one.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $date_field = $('#edit-field-deadline');

$date_field.find('label').first().html($date_field.find('.fieldset-legend').html());
$date_field.find('.date-padding').appendTo($date_field);
$date_field.find('fieldset').hide();
```